# Under California law, where are all the unmarked crosswalks located?

Tags: california, traffic, vehicle

As I understand, "unmarked crosswalk" refers to any area implicitly defined by the law as a crosswalk. For example, an unmarked crosswalk usually exists where one road meets another.

CVC 21949-21971 provides the pedestrian rules, but does not define "unmarked crosswalk "

Comment: Interesting question. If a crosswalk is defined by markings, an "unmarked crosswalk" lacks definition, unless there exists somewhere a list of all the unmarked crosswalks. What we do know however is that "unmarked crosswalks" very specifically do _not_ exist where markings indicate pedestrians may not cross.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CVC section 275 defines "crosswalk":

http://codes.findlaw.com/ca/vehicle-code/veh-sect-275.html

An unmarked crosswalk is simply a crosswalk that isn't marked.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. Basically any intersection, including T-intersections or half T-intersections (the ones that if you walk across, you'll be in the center middle lane; I don't know a better name). Basically any right-angle intersection except marked "no crossing" or having stoplights is okay to walk? That's basically almost every intersection, but I don't see people walking on unmarked crosswalks at intersections in California, at least -- most people consider it jaywalking despite the law saying otherwise.

Comment: @CreativiTimothy Just read the section, my own reading is that an unmarked crosswalk can exist at intersections with sidewalks as per (a), but without sidewalks, it must be marked as per (b). But otherwise I agree with your reading.

Comment: @CreativiTimothy The typical Californian is unlikely to be aware of what the law really is and operates on an admixture of whatever "legal" stories have entered their mind.  They know about jaywalking as something about walking across the street, they know it's a crime somewhere, so they just assume that jaywalking is a crime pretty much everywhere and applies to anything not involving a crosswalk (outside a residential area at least).  There's also the safety factor of crossing at marked crosswalks only, especially in high traffic metropolitan areas.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know about california...but [here is what I could find for new jersey](https://www.state.nj.us/transportation/commuter/pedsafety/crosswalks.shtm):  Basically a crosswalk is an area either marked by markings as a crosswalk, or unmarked as it has a different pavement than the rest of the road... But by this definition, I should be able to walk on the shoulder of a highway, so i am not completely sure.

Comment: this is not a chat room. When asking quetions her they expect good grammer an punctualization.